# How can I create a Markdown table with several columns under column?

Tags: markdown

How can I create a Markdown table like here?

[image]

This is what I tried:

[image]

Comment: I have inlined the images for you. [The second one shouldn't be an image at all](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577)—it is Markdown source code. Images can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I merge table rows in markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46621765/can-i-merge-table-rows-in-markdown)

Comment: And please don't tag spam. This has _nothing_ to do with Excel, Google Sheets, or data tables.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way***, *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface.*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71331898/edit). Thanks in advance.